# Probabilistic model for a variable which depends on its previous value

Tags: probability

I am solving a problem in which the future value of a variable depends on its current value. Assume we are talking about temperature `t`, we are given a constant `c` such that `0<c<1`. If today's temperature is `t0` then tomorrow's temperature will be within the range `[t0*(1-c) , t0*(1+c)]`.

I am wondering if normal or exponential distribution will be a reasonable model for `t`; as in my case the variable `t` is not totally independent of the previous value (which means it is not memoryless. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution)

Comment: This seems to confuse the absolute distribution of `t`and the stochastic dynamics `t_0`$\to$`t`. Which one interests you?

Comment: I am interested in the absolute distribution of `t`. Maybe I should also be interested in the stochastic dynamics, but I don't know what that is.

Comment: Then the question describes no reason whatsoever to go for a normal or exponential distribution rather than any other distribution.

Comment: @Did  are you saying that an exponential distribution will work in my case? Did you want to say: 'no reason whatsoever *not* to go ...'?

Comment: very curious to know if there is such a probability distribution